# How could i draw a Sequence diagram with different ui

Tags: uml, sequence

I would like to ask a general question for drawing a sequence diagram with the entity, boundary and control classes.

I intend to create a program that have this button "display options" and then when i click on it it will show other available options. How should I draw a sequence diagram for flow of this program e.g after I click "Display button" the other options appear, and I can click on the option to open a new page. Must I make each options a boundary since when I click it it open up in another page too? If I need to model the options as a boundary, I would like to ask is it logical for boundary to communicate with boundary directly? I am not really sure what control class to add for opening a new page.

I apologise if my question is too vague as I am still in the design stage and I have no working sample.

Comment: There are several software development methods (most notably the Rational Unified Process) and text books that advocate using the entity/boundary/control concepts in sequence diagrams. Are you following a particular one?

Comment: I am following uml v2.4.1 for my project.

Comment: UML (any version) does not mention the entity/boundary/control concept. As far as UML is concerned, you may use your own definition of entity/boundary/control classes. You may follow Thomas Kilian's guidelines, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need separate boundaries for each dialog. You simply can have a boundary that covers a whole dialog area where you just present certain parts of the needed information. However, a boundary should represent a specific number of related information items. E.g. you might have a boundary called "Personal Information" that might present name, birthday and address. But it might also be a good idea to have an "Address" boundary which is about general addresses. When you design a system, your business objects (like Person and Address) will pop up and you will eventually construct boundaries to represent them.

When using a boundary in a SD you just pass messages to it that tell which information items are displayed/read.

For example a SD could look like this:

[image]

You could also create extra boundaries for Option1 and Option2. But from the context this is (hopefully) clear that you have option lists which are treated separately (in the same form). If you want to make clear that a separate form is needed you would create extra boundaries (e.g. if it's a complex dialog).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know of any page which have similar sequence diagram to what I would like to draw? I am sorry I am trying to understand your suggestion but I can't visualise it.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: You say "... a boundary should ...".  According to which methodology or text book?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Well, "my own" :-) which has proven to be practicable. I'll try to find evidence elsewhere...

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Yuck - everybody seems to talk about boundaries as simply interfaces (screens, web pages, etc.). I think that's a to wide definition. When a system communicates with an actor it's never a melange of information but always a sub-domain (like in my example the `Options`). And that should be expressed by the name of the boundary. Makes sense? I'd say so.